# Sometimes I need to click one of my bootstrap checkbox buttons a second time. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This works 60% of the time.  But sometimes I need to click a button a second time.  Of course that will not fly in the real web-world.  I'm using a modified bootstrap-min, which may be a no-no to allow another style of button.  Just imagine they are the same as "data-color=primary".  "data-color=icomold" is the only addition.

Here is the important parts for you to troubleshoot:
The buttons...

```
            <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="icomold">Injection Mold</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"/>
                </span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;                
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="icomold">Export Mold</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"/>
                </span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;                
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="icomold">CNC Plastic</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"/>
                </span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;                
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="icomold">CNC Metal</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"/>
                </span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;                
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="icomold">Urethane Casting</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Then here is the script piece:

```
        $(function() {
        $('.button-checkbox').each(function() {

            // Settings
            var $widget = $(this),
        $button = $widget.find('button'),
        $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
        color = $button.data('color'),
        settings = {
            on: {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
            },
            off: {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
            }
        };

            // Event Handlers
            $button.on('click', function() {
                $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
                $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
                updateDisplay();
            });
            $checkbox.on('change', function() {
                updateDisplay();
            });

            // Actions
            function updateDisplay() {
                var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

                // Update the button's color
                    if (isChecked) {
                        //We've activated one
                        //now we need to deactivate the rest of the buttons
                        //var elm = document.createElement("div");
                        var y = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-icomold active');
                        var aNode = y[0];
                        if (typeof (aNode) != "undefined" && $button.context.innerText != aNode.innerText) 
                        {
                            aNode.className = "btn btn-default";
                            var state = aNode.childNodes[0]
                            state.className = "state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked";
                        }

                        $button
                        .removeClass('btn-default')
                        .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');

                    }
                    else {
                        $button
                        .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                        .addClass('btn-default');
                    }

                    // Set the button's state
                    $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

                    // Set the button's icon
                    $button.find('.state-icon')
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);
            }

            // Initialization
            function init() {

                updateDisplay();

                // Inject the icon if applicable
                if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                    $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
                }
            }
            init();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Does it work as expected with normal buttons (not icomold)?

Comment: Re: Clint - I switched all to data-color=primary.  And the same issue is happening.  The 'deactivate' routine in the script may be the culprit.  No errors are generated.  Here is the really odd part.  When the visual-error occurs the button stays highlighted gray.  As if I was still hovering over it.  However, I can find no difference in the DOM'S CSS information between one darker button and the next.

Comment: As written, if you click on the `<button>` element, `updateDisplay()` gets invoked once, once in the button's `click` handler, and once in the checkbox's `change` handler.  Is there any unintended consequence from executing it twice?

Comment: It does execute twice, I noticed that.  This code is taken from a couple of sources.  I used to be good at scripting and only now getting back into it.  Actually is there any reason I need two different event handlers at all?  I'll experiment with removing the checkbox one.

Comment: hmm.. I can comment out the $checkbox.on('change'... and I get the same functionality (no change in appearance).  There are distinct differences.  Now it only hits the function once.  However the problem is perhaps more clear.  Not the solution (to me).  On a "failure" sequence.  When it hits the 'UpdateDisplay' function 'isChecked' gets false, but it should get true.  Then it goes into the 'Else' part of 'UpdateDisplay'.

Comment: I'm clicking on a new unchecked/uncolored button.  This happens intermittently.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixes.

```
 function updateDisplay(from) {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');
            isChecked = from;
```

So for my purposes, I don't care what the original value was.
On the Init and the one event I'm sending what it needs to change to.

```
// Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay(false);
```

False from the initialization... And True from the 'Click' event.  For my purpose: There is no reason to have an unclick event.

```
// Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function() {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay(true);
        });
```

Kudos above to Dossy for emphasizing that the UpdateDisplay was happening twice.
And this part needed to be commented out:

```
    //$checkbox.on('change', function() {
    //          updateDisplay();
    //    });
```

Comment: I will comment that this never really answered the original question as said.  However I can move on with finishing the page next week and all is well.